MOSFETs keep shorting way below rated current
I'm currently building a small stud welder, which I'm trying to control with IRF1405 MOSFETs (rated at 55 V.) The circuit operates at 48 V and I'm controlling the current and welding time by switching MOSFETs, of which there are multiple in parallel, each individually controlled.
The MOSFETs keep frying and permanently shorting at currents of about 100 A per MOSFET (current limited by a 0.5 Ω resistor made from a straight piece of nichrome wire at <50 V,) even though they are rated for over 75 A permanent and up to 680 A pulse current. The duration for welding is 5 ms (just one short pulse per weld,) and the MOSFETs are attached to a big chunk of aluminium (even though heat can't flow that fast.) 100 A really shouldn't kill them in 5 ms.
The Arduino controls the MOSFET by giving the 5 ms pulse to a PC817 optocoupler with a 100 Ω series resistor and a 10 kΩ pull-down resistor on the input and output side. The input capacitance of the optocoupler is 250 pF, and of the MOSFET it is 5480 pF.  This should cause the optocoupler to switch on in less than 1 µs and off in about 10 µs, and the MOSFET to switch on in about 5 µs and off in less than 0.5 ms, therefore not causing the MOSFET to stay on much longer than expected.
This poses the question of what goes wrong in my setup. Is there a general thinking error in my circuit, or am I just expecting too much from these MOSFETs?


48 V is a big high, especially if you are "touching" the wires ... Have you tried at a lower voltage (12 V)?

Note that the current ratings on FETs are specified with a given case temperature.  100 A through a 5 mOhm FET is 50 W.  Unless you can remove that 50 W your case temperature will rise well above where the current is specified and turn your FET into something that is no longer a FET.

48V is a bit high relative to the 55V rating. At these levels of current, every little bit of parasitic inductance matters, and can easily produce voltage spikes that exceed the device rating. I doubt that a single 51V zener is enough protection.

So I am actually expecting too much from the Mosfets? I thought that 50W for 1/200 of a second, resulting in 0.25J of energy would be ok. If you calculate this energy to be deposited in the 100mm³ of surrounding copper material of the Mosfet, this would cause a heat increase of less than 1 K. Why would the Mosfet be rated so high if it can't even switch one 100A pulse without frying? So I'm guessing I need to go far lower, probably starting with half the voltage. Also, any Idea for additional protection against parasitic inductance?

My comment was just an example of how you have to be careful with FET specs, I don't know if your FETs would be in trouble with 5 ms 100 A pulses, there are too many variables and unknowns.  But 200 ms can be a long time as far as the die is concerned.

I just tested the circuit at 24V and it immediately fried the mosfet as well, even though not as bad as before (the fried mosfet has a drain-source resistance of about 1 Ω, whereas the ones fried at 48V had no measurable drain-source-resistance). But I guess that the inductance mentioned might be the problem then, at 24v and 0.5Ω the current should be 50A, which is even far below the constant current rating.

0.5 Ohm is a bit high in the source of MOSFET  ... You can use also a "burst" of N pulses in place of 1 "large" pulse.

Might the error be that I put the current limiting resistor at the source, not the drain?

I think it is not the "right" place ... You should change the polarity of MOSFETs.

Good question and a lovely set of comments and answers. This is the sort of question and answer set that really helps the site - and of course the people who ask :-)

The limiting resistor is killing your FETs. I wrote an answer with an explanation. tl;dr; High current brings up source voltage so high that $V_{GS}$ is insufficient.

CRUCIAL Several people have commented about the 0.5 ohm source resistor.  At 24A source current the source is at gate voltage and you have ZERO gate drive. The circuit has no chance of working correctly. Rather as the source resistor voltage rises the FET will come out of saturation and very very rapidly destroy the FET. || The 100 Ohm gate resistors are (almost certainly) far too high. Maybe 10 Ohms. || The 10K turnoff pulldowns will give a massively slow turnoff. ||You should provide FET pkg and a data sheet link.  ||Also an opto ds link.

Presumably FET is in this pkg  family. https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf1405zpbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355db17fa18c1 . Please advise. Please add ALL extra details in your question - not in comments.

tl;dr; Put the limiting resistor to drain and use a high side driver.
The answer is simpler than we all thought first. The limiting resistor is on the wrong pin of the FET. Nevertheless all previous answers are correct and related to several aspects of the problem.
As others have already pointed out you have to pass the linear region of the FETs characteristics to reach saturation. Outside saturation region thermic losses in your FETs are tremendous. Your driving circuit doesn't ensure a quick charge/discharge of the associated capacitances.
There are several issues contributing to this, namely the parasitics of wiring, the poor driving capacity of your opto coupler and so on.
But there's another effect which will hamper your tries. You do not know the conductivity of your welding spot. The welding spot either creates an ohmic contact with a rather low to medium resistance or if not formed "boldly" results in arcing. Arcing currents have a negative resistance characteristic which can form an oscillator together with the capacitances and inductances of the wiring.
Insufficient \$V_{GS}\$
Let's focus on the first issue first. Let's wildly assume your welding spot reaches 2 Ohms either because the contact isn't good from the beginning or as a consequence of the rapid heating of the metals involved. You do not state how many of the FETs are paralleled for your circuit so let's assume it is a single one only and it sees 2 Ohms as its "share" of the conductivity of the welding spot.
You then can see a voltage divider consisting of the "limiting" resistor and the resistance of the welding spot. With this resistances we can assume the input voltage of the circuit as still stable. The voltage over the limiting resistor is then almost 10 V. Clearly the remaining 2 V something for \$V_{GS}\$ is too low to drive the MOSFET into saturation. To adress this, the limiting resistor has to be placed on the drain side of the FET.
Parasitic inductances
Now, the resistances of the welding spot are pretty unpredictable. Hence even the wiring resistances of the single FETs may be so high that they bring up the voltage at source too much to stay in saturation continuously. And leaving saturation means leaving SOA (safe operation area) as defined by manufacturers. On top of that you have to deal with the inductance of the source wire of the FET. When switching too fast, it can even bring up source voltage so high that \$V_{GS}\$ drops to insufficient values.
A low inductance ground plane is paramount. Nevertheless it is strongly recommended to use a dedicated high side driver even if you think you aren't operating on high side. A high side driver will keep most problems away. The high side driver has its reference potential tied to the source pin of the FET directly so it will provide a good \$V_{GS}\$ regardless any resistances and inductances of the other parts of the wiring.
Uncontrollable oscillations
As others have pointed out, a flyback diode is recommended. This is necessary to address the high power oscillator which can build up thanks to the differential negative resistance of an arcing connection in conjunction with the reactive elements.
I have encountered similar effects in highly engineered designs. We had a properly designed half bridge fried over many design steps. The half bridge was "protected" by another perfectly designed FET stage in series with the half bridge. Even with the protection FETs in perfect ON condition the inductance of the protection FETs was high enough to bring the half brigde out of saturation long enough to destroy it. And this with only few amps on a PCB with dozens of thick ground layers connected by half a million of vias.
Timing differences
Last but not least for paralleling switching circuits you have to ensure synchronous switching. Maybe I'm wrong but I think you have tied your circuit together without matching cable lengths and hence matching cable inductances. This can lead to a single MOSFET bearing the main thermal load while crossing linear region because of some little timing differences. Again a properly selected dedicated driver IC can alleviate those issues, because you only have to wire up the firing signal to your FETs over relevant distances.
Use IGBTs if possible
One final thought: „Real“ high power circuits nowadays are built using IGBTs. In a project I'm working on currently IGBTs are used in a circuit breaker for disrupting short circuits of 100 kA and more undamaged. In fact your application is one really predestined for IGBTs. IGBTs have much higher \$V_{CE}\$ in comparison to FET's \$V_{DS}\$ at similar sizes and power ratings. This helps in addressing voltage spikes from inductances. IGBTs are better at lower switching frequencies, and your switching frequency is low.

Thank you very much. I see that there are a lot of things that I didn't consider. I wil learn about IGBTs and completely reconsider my circuit design. Since I destroyed 18 of the 20 MOSFETs I bought, I need to buy new switches anyway.

After looking into IGBTs for two hours, I bought two used 600V 400A industrial IGBTs from ebay for a few bucks. If this isn't enough to weld M3 to M6 studs, probably nothing is. All I need to do now is design a driving circuit with all the considerations from this post in mind.

You're using the term "saturation" here as it applies to BJTs; in MOSFETs, "saturation" and "linear" mean the same thing. You want "ohmic", I believe. || Separately, I think "real" high-power circuits are actually beginning to move away from IGBTs as SiC MOSFETs become more affordable. The lower losses and higher switching speeds attainable with FETs can be a big advantage.

@Hearth Sorry, maybe some of my wordings are influenced by what I was taught at university. As this was a German university they used German lingo. Not all correspond to typical English lingo. Go ahead and correct my answer if you are sure about it.

The MOSFETs will be subject to extreme stress when attempting to switch off with your circuit (and switching 'on' isn't so great either).
There's only a 10kΩ resistor to drain away a couple hundred nC of gate charge. You have to include the effect from the Miller capacitance too, so it's longer than you were expecting. I've shown a comparison here with a somewhat better gate drive arrangement (yours is the cyan).

Also, note that the conduction current rating in the datasheet is a bit fanciful. Consider the fine print in the datasheet:

Package limitation current is 75A


Your graph is very helpful. The switching causes a large absorbtion of energy because of the "semi-on" state that increases the mosfets resistance drastically while still conducting. I will try to create much faster switching to reduce the the integral of power over time, and thereby the spike in junction temperature. Also, I will probably add a Zener Diode in parallel with each Mosfet, just to make sure any of the wild effects of the welding arc will pass by the Mosfet. I will get back once I tried it.

Ok, I just tried to increase the switching speed by about 10x. The MOSFET didn't fry at 24V like before, and even at 48V it just "barely" fried. With the previous circuit, the drain-source-resistance when not powered would drop to almost 0 Ω when frying the MOSFET, with this circuit it dropped to 3 Ω which indicates that the silicone got destroyed a lot less. I think my future approach to this build will be to not only make sure the switching speed is high, but also stay far below the specifications of all used components. Thanks for the help.

Oh, and just one more comment: For the last test, I put the current limiting resistor on the high side of the MOSFET as advised in another comment, this might also have helped in preventing the MOSFET from frying that easily.

Probably killing them with exceeding temperature specs.
It's likely that the current of 96A and 48V is out of the safe operating area. I can't really tell with the log scale, but it looks like it is (see graph below). If that isn't it then its probably switching time:

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF1405-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355db084a18bb
During switching at one point the mosfet will dissipate 4000W (for a short period of time) I^2*R where I is 96A and R is equal to the current limiting resistor (max power when resistance is equal)
If you do switch these mosfets it needs to happen fast (faster than 100us), but it's also likely that the voltages are just too high. I didn't look at the opto switching time, but it's likely that its much slower than 100us.
Either switch the mosfet, make more mosfet circuits to parallel (use the same gate voltage if you parallel so there is no way they will turn on at different times).

With 0.5 ohm in series, the current won't be 96A if there is 48V over the MOSFET. The highest load point during switching would be 24V over MOSFET and 48 A current, which is within the 1 millisec limit.

First problem to solve is not reaching saturation at all. See my answer. But if the circuit is modified to reach saturation your answer will adress remaining problems.

@jpa If the gates could ever switch unevenly, then one device could receive the full current. Until you ensure the schematic is switching properly, you need to assume 96A

@VoltageSpike Even if the devices switch unevenly, each MOSFET has 0.5 ohm in series. With 48 V supply, it is not possible for the FET to simultaneously have Vds = 48V and Id = 96 A.

@jpa What if one device turns on and not the other?

@VoltageSpike Even if there is only a single MOSFET in series with 0.5 ohm resistor, it will never have Vds = 48V and Id = 96A if supply is 48V. The resistor will drop part of the voltage.

All straight wire has an inductance that varies in uH/m depending on the log of the wire gauge or L/W ratio. 0.6~0.8 uH/m typ. (Coiled wire has more L. ) Also when an arc breaks current abruptly, current loop inductance will change the flyback voltage by a basic formula of V=LdI/dt so there must be some snubber design with low inductance to clamp the over-voltage in the design and minimize the inductance and protect the FET with an ultrafast response.
Scope your setup with 5V rather than 48V and verify your turn-on/off and RdOn changes with temperature and flyback then scope the drain voltage. reduce Rs to 0.05 ohm to raise Id.
You will need a bunch of parallel FETs + Rs current limited to handle 100A for a single 5 ms max pulse from the SOA curves, rather than sharing a common resistor as the PTC thermal effects of current sharing may not be fast enough.
The absolute maximum is 560 mJ so derate this 50% and compute your VI*t=E =250 mJ max with Rs current limiting for each FET with wire from a 5V supply to share the energy needed to bond.  Heatsinks will be required for frequent use. An ultra-low ESR cap is essential to store the energy between the charge and discharge voltage levels. Then you may need a tungsten tip.
Suggestion: How to distribute the remote control switch energy (start with 5V to validate ringing and flyback voltage.)

posthoc  comment
I was curious about the \$R/L=1/\tau\$ values of nichrome vs copper wire, so I did some calculations for the straight wire to see how it resonates with Coss of FETs.  SiC FETs or IGBTs may be preferred in this solution, with much smaller \$R_{On}*C_{out} = \tau\$ values.
\$ \dfrac{R}{L}=\dfrac{2ρ}{μ_0⋅d^2⋅ln⁡(4ld)}\$​
Where:
\$ μ_0 = 4π⋅10^{−7}\$  [H/m] Permeability of free space
l = wire length [m]
d = wire diameter [m]
1.0 mm wire L'≈ 1.4 μH/m
0.1 mm wire L'≈ 2.8 μH/m

Adding current limit R reduces the wire's natural time constant, Tau significantly.
If the Nichrome wire circuit is short (cm), inductance is less likely to be a problem.

If you had put the 0.5 Ω into the simulation you might have seen that it's unlikely to switch on the MOSFET properly at all. But all objections are right, given the limiting resistor is omitted.

@Ariser  Pardon me for not stating my assumptions of reducing the pulse width to 1ms and reducing  0.5 Ω to 0.1 Ω. But yes moving heat from the 5 mΩ FET to the resistors in the drain is essential. MPT says it may be only 50% efficient per pulse.  This is just a hint while omitting the obvious RLC and Q effects with Cout.

I think the "drive" of the MOSFETs is not "good".
Tried this kind of circuit with 5 paralleled BUZ71A MOSFETs for ~ 400 A.
The "spot" welding is at level "ground".
You should try this one. Need an inverter as "driver".
Note that the 10 mOhm "is" one 100 mOhm per MOSFET.
Note also that the realization may need some "good" rules for "mounting" the MOSFETs.
IRF9540 has a current max of 72A (pulse). I limited it ~ 25 A.

Note that if you use an inductive short-circuit, you should add a diode (d1) to prevent "high" voltage. Note also the negative pulse across the load which reduces the Vds maximum voltage you can use.

You can ("must") add a diode through "short-circuit" R1-L1.
Here is the behavior.


I will only address the Zener diode (and a note on gate drive).  A 51V Zener does NOT hard-clip the voltage to 51V.  Looking at the first datasheet I found, Rohm KDZLVTR51, a 1W part:

VZ = 48V to 54V, at which voltage the diode will draw 2 mA.
VZ is strongly temperature-dependent (this coefficient varies with Zener voltage; there's a low voltage at which Zeners have a very low tempco).  For a nominal 51V part, about 49V to 55V variation over a wide temperature range.
Dynamic impedance at that point is 220 ohms.  If it was linear (which it isn't) an increase in current of 1mA would be accompanied by a 220mV increase in voltage.
Curves show an increase of 1V at 20mA, conversely at (nominal) 52V it will sink 20mA.  How much current do you need to clip?

You might need more of an active clamping device.
Gate drive:
You need to snap-action the MOSFET into and out of saturation, to minimize dissipation (if you use MOSFETs; if using IGBTs then research them).  There are gate drive ICs designed to do this; they will have recommended circuits and design notes.
Gradual turn-on or turn-off will result in very high dissipation in the MOSFET and release of the magic smoke that makes them work.
